# Inconsistent indent QGIS

Tags: qgis, python

I try to set some qwidgets on fields in a Qgis Project, but i have an error of inconsistent dedent at **elif field.name() == 'syst':**. Made so far:

```
def load(self):
map_layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()
for layer in map_layers:
    if layer.name() == 'MAT_CANA':
        mat_canaId = layer.id()
    elif layer.name() == 'Collecteur':
        CollecteurId = layer.id()
    elif layer.name() == 'FORME_CHAMBRE':
        FormeChambreId = layer.id()
    elif layer.name() == 'Genre_Chambre':
        GenreChambreId = layer.id()
    elif layer.name() == 'MAT_CHMB_COU':
        MaterialChambreCouId = layer.id()
    elif layer.name() == 'PRECISION':
        PrecisionId = layer.id()
    elif layer.name() == 'SYSTEM_ECOULE':
        SystemEcouleId = layer.id()
for layer in map_layers:
    if '"public"."chambre_eau_provisoire"' in layer.source():
        layer.setEditForm('C:/Users/george.vina/Desktop/BOUDRY/Forme/formeUi/chambrePr.ui')
        fields = layer.pendingFields()
        for field in fields:
            if field.name() == 'genre_cham':
               fieldIndex = layer.fieldNameIndex('genre_cham')
               layer.setEditorWidgetV2(fieldIndex,'ValueRelation')
               layer.setEditorWidgetV2Config(fieldIndex,{'Layer': GenreChambreId,'Key': 'genre_chambre', 'Value': 'genre_chambre'}) 
            elif field.name() == 'syst':
               fieldIndex = layer.fieldNameIndex('syst')
               layer.setEditorWidgetV2(fieldIndex,'ValueRelation')
               layer.setEditorWidgetV2Config(fieldIndex,{'Layer': SystemEcouleId,'Key': 'system_ecoule', 'Value': 'system_ecoule'})
            elif field.name() == 'type_chamb':
               fieldIndex = layer.fieldNameIndex('type_chamb')
               layer.setEditorWidgetV2(fieldIndex,'ValueRelation')
               layer.setEditorWidgetV2Config(fieldIndex,{'Layer': FormeChambreId,'Key': 'forme_chambre', 'Value': 'forme_chambre'})
            elif field.name() == 'mat_chamb':
               fieldIndex = layer.fieldNameIndex('mat_chamb')
               layer.setEditorWidgetV2(fieldIndex,'ValueRelation')
               layer.setEditorWidgetV2Config(fieldIndex,{'Layer': MaterialChambreCouId,'Key': 'mat_chmb_cou', 'Value': 'mat_chmb_cou'})
            elif field.name() == 'type_couve':
                fieldIndex = layer.fieldNameIndex('type_couve')
                layer.setEditorWidgetV2(fieldIndex,'ValueRelation')
                layer.setEditorWidgetV2Config(fieldIndex,{'Layer': MaterialChambreCouId,'Key': 'mat_chmb_cou', 'Value': 'mat_chmb_cou'})
```

Comment: Try indenting everything after your first line `def load(self):`.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, the problem it is before first elif. I formatted with Idlle editor from python. The problem is resolved, too much tabs.

Comment: I think your problem is using IDLE as the editor =). Personally, I use Sublime.